# Ensemble of boolean predictors

Tags: predictor, ensemble-learning

Lets say we have a 0/1 predictor, that is right in p % of cases.
If we ensemble N of those uncorrelated predictors, what is (an elegant solution for) their accuracy? (The ensemble's answer is the most voted variant.)

(Disclaimer: Not a homework, just came across this and I believe that there must be some more elegant solution than doing it by hand)

Comment: My original question states uncorrelated.

Comment: OK, misread it. But uncorrelated predictors are not very realistic. If they were trained on same data, predicting the same thing, then you would want them to be correlated with the predicted labels, and if all the predictions are correlated with the labels then, in real life, there would be some correlation between the predictors as well.

Comment: I am not talking about realiatic case. For uncorrelated it is the exact accuracy, for a real case it is an upper bound. And that is important to know also!

Comment: But it is not an upper bound! Imagine that you have strongly correlated and very accurate classifiers, combining them would mean that the ensemble predicts correctly a lot of cases they agree on (reminder: they are strongly correlated) and in cases where any single classifier made a mistake, ensembling it with other classifiers gives you a chance to correct the mistakes. Also for the classifiers to be uncorrelated, they would not need to agree in classifications, hence they would need to have poor performance, so this cannot be upper bound.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion, I think you have enlightened me.

Now I still am interested in this question being answered, because I wonder on how the plots would look with respect to "N" and "p". Are you able to guide me to the solution?
You can rest assured, that I will not use it now for any wrongdoings.